# How to show performance counter results in texbox.text windows forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey guys I`m new to c# and I learned a lot from reading answers on this community.

I`m trying to create a performance monitoring system
I did through the console ,but when it comes to windows forms I have a problem in viewing my results to the user.
here is the code I used (yes i included System.Diagnostics)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //test
            PerformanceCounter CpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "%Processor Time", "_Total");
           //textBox1.Text = CpuCount.NextValue().ToString();
            textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0} %", CpuCount.NextValue());

        }
    }
}

//textBox1.Text = CpuCount.NextValue().ToString();
//textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0} %", CpuCount.NextValue());
```

these two lines I found while searching to get the output to show in `textBox1.Text`
but it shows as blank when I run the program.

Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Even the `textBox1.Text = CpuCount.NextValue().ToString();` didn't work? You know you're in trouble when even ToString() can't save you...

Comment: looks like you have Form1_Load method, but haven't subscribed to Form.Load event, so Form1_Load  never executes

Comment: thank you for your replies the answer active92 provided solved the issue by adding a space between % and Processor Time.

however ,  the percentage stays at 0% ... how can I have an incrementing value changing in this box? sorry I`m farily new but I thought using .NextValue(); will always refresh the output value .. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a space between `%` and `Processor Time`

```
PerformanceCounter CpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

To update the counter, you'll need a timer.

```
private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitialiseCPUCounter();
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float tmp = cpuCounter.NextValue();
    textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0} %", tmp);
}

private void InitialiseCPUCounter()
{
   cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
}
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked!! but it stays at 0% ... how can I have an incrementing value changing in this box? sorry I`m farily new but I thought using .NextValue(); will always refresh the output value .. I appreciate your help

Comment: @Lupin glad it helped. kindly please accept the answer.

Comment: @Lupin first of all, because you put your code in form_load which means it is getting the value only once. Also, nextvalue returns a calculated value. It is not a refresh. Secondly, i think you might need to create a new question for this.

Comment: when I try to run the code its underlining timer1.Start();
is there a reference or using system ... missing?

Comment: @Lupin sorry, my bad. forgot to tell you that you need to add a timer at your form